# Webpages cannot access folders. (IIS)

Tags: iis, directory, asp.net, http-status-code-403

What setting must I change under IIS to allow access to the folders? I am looking for that settings for hours, nothing found.

It seems like it is giving a 403 error when I tried to access the folder.

PS, I am only using localhost.

Comment: What do you mean by "allow access to folders?" Do you mean allow users to browse folders? Also which version of IIS?

Comment: This question really belongs on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 1):

IIS Directory Browsing:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you'll need to enable the IIS user account, or IUSR_[MachineName] account access to that folder.  Right-click on the folder, select "Properties", then select the "Security" tab, and add the user "IUSR_[YourMachineName]" in there.  The "[MachineName]" is usually the "From This Location" box above and is just the network name of your computer.  Give them read & execute, and perhaps modify permissions if you think necessary.